# Array like struct of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I have one question about array and how auto resize an array.
I see vector does it automatically but vectors are for one dimension only.
So I think a `struct` of vectors could be good.

```
#include <vector>
struct 2dimensionarray
{ 
    vector<int> 1dimension;
    vector<int> 2dimension;
}
```

So is this a good way? Or there are better ways to do it?

Comment: Why not a vector of vectors?

Comment: tried vector of vectors: `vector <vector<int>> x` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a vector that is two dimensions you nest the vector in the template part:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> 2dvector_name;
```

If you need more then two dimensions you would do the same thing:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> 3dvector_name;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>> 4dvector_name;
etc...
```

Comment: but you know numbers as first charakter in variable names are forbidden in c- like languages...

Comment: I edited to make it more clear the name is just a place holder.  I just want to make sure they understood what dimension the vector has.

Comment: thanks for help me. im too noob